# Problema simples de alinhamento CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou a 3 horas com esse problema simples, primeiro trabalho do curso.

Gostaria de deixar assim:[image: Gostaria de deixa assim]

```css
#conteudo{
  background-color: #F5F5F6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  right: 10%;
}

.bloco{
  display: inline;
}

.bloco img{
  height: 212px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="conteudo">
    <div class="bloco">
        <img src="https://feitocasulo.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/capa-quadrada.jpg" />
        <h1>Texto exemplo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, marcar como resolvido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar o `float: left;`

```css
#conteudo{
  background-color: #F5F5F6;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  right: 10%;
}

.bloco{
  display: inline;
}

.bloco img{
  height: 212px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo">
    <div class="bloco">
        <img src="https://feitocasulo.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/capa-quadrada.jpg" />
        <h1>Texto exemplo</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```